# Remove duplicated Vector at dictionary in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia

I am looking for solution to remove duplicated value in vector which is in dictionary format at Julia.

Here is my dictionary :

```
x = Dict{AbstractString,Array{Integer,1}}("A" => [1,2,3], "B" => [3,4,5], "C" => [5,6,7])
```

and below is expected output :

```
Dict{AbstractString, Vector{Integer}} with 3 entries:
"A" => [1, 2]
"B" => [4]
"C" => [6, 7]
```

Comment: why do you drop `3` but keep `5`?

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński Thanks I edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively short way to do it (I have not optimized it for full speed to keep the solution short):

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> x = Dict{AbstractString,Array{Integer,1}}("A" => [1,2,3], "B" => [3,4,5], "C" => [5,6,7])
Dict{AbstractString, Vector{Integer}} with 3 entries:
  "B" => [3, 4, 5]
  "A" => [1, 2, 3]
  "C" => [5, 6, 7]

julia> dups = [k for (k, v) in countmap(Iterators.flatten(values(x))) if v > 1]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 3

julia> foreach(v -> setdiff!(v, dups), values(x))

julia> x
Dict{AbstractString, Vector{Integer}} with 3 entries:
  "B" => [4]
  "A" => [1, 2]
  "C" => [6, 7]
```

If anything is not clear in the code please comment.

This solution updates your dictionary `x` in-place as I assumed this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Or, pedestrian-style

```
allvalues(x::AbstractDict) = reduce(vcat, collect(values(x)))

function finddups(x::AbstractArray) 
    dups = Int[]
    filter(item -> item in dups ? true : begin
    push!(dups, item)
    false end, x)
end
    
x = Dict{AbstractString,Array{Integer,1}}("A" => [1,2,3], "B" => [3,4,5], "C" => [5,6,7])
dups = x |> allvalues |> finddups
foreach(v -> setdiff!(v, dups), values(x))
x
```